# setTimeout('classInstance.doFoo(arg)', 750); won't work

Tags: javascript, class, instance, settimeout

I'm trying to call an instance's method with a delay of 750ms. The problem is, it doesn't work. I've read that there's some sort of problem with setInterval and objects so probably there's one with setTimeout as well.

Say I have this:

```
function App()
{
      this.doFoo = function (arg)
      {
          alert("bar");
      }
}

window.app = new App();
setTimeout('app.doFoo(arg)', 750);//doesn't work
app.doFoo(arg); //works
```

Is there a workaround? How do I go about passing the instance and function to setTimeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function App()
{
    this.doFoo = function (arg) {
        alert(arg);
    }
}

window.app = new App();
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.app.doFoo('arg');
}, 750);
```

Comment: Explanation: If you pass a string to setTimeout, then Javascript has to `eval` it to run the code. `eval`led code is executed in a different scope than your main code, so your variable references can easily break. Much better to pass an anonymous function to setTimeout and then your variables will all be in the right scope

Comment: @Gareth, great explanation, please feel free to edit my answer and include this valuable information.

Comment: @Ross: If you don't know then don't worry, because `eval` causes far more problems than it solves. It's a way of taking a string of code and running it as if it was the actual code it represents. What makes it complicated is how local variables and arguments are dealt with. It's much easier to create an anonymous function (as Darin does here) which performs the same action.

Answer (score 2):

i think the previous answer needs a little tweak.  it is setting a global variable that you are then calling; if you really want to call an instance of your 'class' try this.

```
function App(message){
     this.name = 'instance';
     var self = this;
     var x = setTimeout(function(){self.doFoo(message, x);}, 750);
}
App.prototype.name = 'proto';

//creating the function on the prototype is more efficient since it is only created once.  if you do 'this.doFoo = function(){}' it's created for every instance of the function taking more memory.

App.prototype.doFoo = function(arg, timer){
 clearTimeout(timer);
 alert(this.name +' ' + arg)
}

var x = new App("hello world");
//should output ("instance hello world");
```